# MediaElementJS and Phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, video, mediaelement.js

Hej 
I'm trying to run MediaElementJs in a hybrid app with phonegap.
It works fine as webapp without phonegap but not in combination. The videotag doesn't play any video.

I'm using Phonegap 2.1.0 and Android 2.1 (also android 2.2.3 for testing)

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't fit togehter and how I resolve that problem?

Thanks in advance

Tobi

Answer (score 0):

We are using MediaElementJS in a native iOS PhoneGap 2.3.0 application without problems. We testet MediaElementJS on Android as well. I suggest to double check your config.